# python 3.5 printing formated float number

Tags: printing, floating-point, format, python-3.5

I've found something interesting with my python3.5

So this is the code

```
previous = 0.1234567891011121314
now = 2.98764627181

print("Before: {0:.15f}".format(float(previous)))
print("Now: {0:.15f}".format(float(now)))


print(" Before:{0:.15f} Now:{0:.15f} ".format(float(previous), float(now)))
```

and this is the result

```
Before: 0.123456789101112
Now: 2.987646271810000
Before:0.123456789101112 Now:0.123456789101112
```

So when I want to print them with one single print and format function
python3.5 seems to not able to handle it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please provide the error or traceback you get that you would like us to help you fix.

Answer (score 1):

The `0` in the `{0:.15f}` replacement field is a *field name*, as specified in [the Python documentation for string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). When the field name is a number, it identifies a positional argument. Since you have `0` in both replacement fields, both are replaced with the positional argument numbered 0.

To use the other argument, use `{1:.15f}`.